# ASP.NET Core MVC - invalid input from form to controller action

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `HomeController`, which returns a View... In my View, I submit a form, which is handled by `ServicesController` and action `SubmitDestination`. **(Error/problem is listed at bottom)**

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ScheduleService.Models.Departure

<form asp-controller="Services" asp-action="SubmitDestination" method="post">
    Departure time: <input asp-for="DepartureTime"/>
    Number: <input asp-for="Number"/>
    Destination<input asp-for="Destination"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**ServicesController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ServicesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Departure SubmitDestination(Departure departure)
    {
        Departure _departure = new Departure
        {
            DepartureTime = departure.DepartureTime,
            Number = departure.Number,
            Destination = departure.Destination
        };

        _db.DepartureDB.Add(_departure);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return _db.DepartureDB.LastOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** When I submit the form, this is the response that is returned in the browser:

```
{"":["The input was not valid."]}
```

Can anyone spot, why my input is invalid? Is there some special rules for API controllers? Thanks

Comment: as error says, you have invalid data compare to what your model is asking. Can you check validations against the request you are receiving in controller?

Comment: @Justcode I tried to remove parameter `(Departure departure)` from method `SubmitDeparture`and it hits the method now. Maybe the method just cant take parameters?

Comment: @thesystem The api controller is most likely expecting JSON by default while the form is posting form encoded data.

Comment: @Nkosi I think you hit the nail on the head. Will try to adjust my code. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: If anyone has an idea to convert form data into JSON without changing my code too much, I'll happily take it

Comment: @thesystem One option would be to remove the form action and controller taghelpers, intercept the submit in Javascript and make an ajax call posting JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `[FromForm]` attribute:

```
public Departure SubmitDestination([FromForm]Departure departure)
```

This instructs the model binder to read the data from `x-www-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

As @Nkosi pointed out in the comments, the API Controller is expection Json, but I am trying to pass in data from the form (which is not Json). I didn't find a solution, but that was the problem

Comment: Why not serialise the form data in a script? It may help you:)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna Yes I will definitely try it when I have time. Thanks :)!